# Firebase Auth: How to determine if a firebase account already exists when using google or apple sign in?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

In my app, I have a sign IN page and a sign-UP page with onboarding flow. If a user wants to sign IN with Google or Apple, I want to check first if there is an existing Firebase account. Otherwise, the user needs to sign UP first.

By now I use the `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` method to check if a Firebase account exists. For Apple sign in this looks like this:

```
Future<String> appleSignInOrSignUp(bool isSignIn) async {
  final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  try {
    final appleUser = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
      scopes: [
        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
      ],
    );

    final email = appleUser.email;
    if (isSignIn && email != null) {
      final list = await _firebaseAuth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email);
      // if there is no firebase account yet, user needs to sign up first
      if (list.isEmpty) return 'Not registered';
    }

    final credential = AppleAuthProvider.credential(
      appleUser.authorizationCode,
    );

    await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    return 'Success';
  } catch (e) {
    return '$e';
  }
}
```

I have two problems with this solution:

1. What happens if a user changes his Google or Apple email? Does the `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` method still work?
2. In the case of Apple, email is only provided on the first authorizations. How to check if there is an account for this Apple user if no email is provided?

Is there a better solution to determine for sure that a user has a Firebase account?

Comment: Have you found a solution, Dalon?

Comment: no, unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

> 1. What happens if a user changes his Google or Apple email? Does the fetchSignInMethodsForEmail method still work?

No, unless you update the [User](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User-class.html) object with the new email, using [User#updateEmail(String newEmail)](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/updateEmail.html) function. Right after the update, [FirebaseAuth#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(String email)](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/fetchSignInMethodsForEmail.html) will return the desired results.

> 2. In the case of Apple, email is only provided on the first authorizations. How to check if there is an account for this Apple user if no email is provided?

The `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` function requires an argument. So without an email address, it will not work.

> Is there a better solution to determine for sure that a user has a Firebase account?

No, as far as I know.

Comment: Hey Dalon. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?